# VPN Not launching on boot

Tags: raspbmc, vpn

I'm using RaspBMC and have set up a VPN using openVPN and PrivateInternetAccess. I've been following the third comment on [this post](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/forum/discussion/3093/raspberry-pi-issues-solved) which I have used previously and has worked. A few weeks ago, it stopped working on boot. If I run it manually, so type

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/London.conf
```

into putty, it works fine, but only until the next time it reboots. The instructions in this post edit the startup file for openVPN, but I've also tried to use a cronjob to launch it on boot with no luck. I'll post the openVPN startup file at the end. Please let me know anything else I should post that may help.
Thanks in advance.

Openvpn startup script:

```
# This is the configuration file for /etc/init.d/openvpn

#
# Start only these VPNs automatically via init script.
# Allowed values are "all", "none" or space separated list of
# names of the VPNs. If empty, "all" is assumed.
# The VPN name refers to the VPN configutation file name.
# i.e. "home" would be /etc/openvpn/home.conf
#
#AUTOSTART="all"
#AUTOSTART="none"
#AUTOSTART="home office"
AUTOSTART="London"
#
# Refresh interval (in seconds) of default status files
# located in /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.status
# Defaults to 10, 0 disables status file generation
#
#STATUSREFRESH=10
#STATUSREFRESH=0
# Optional arguments to openvpn's command line
OPTARGS=""
#
# If you need openvpn running after sendsigs, i.e.
# to let umountnfs work over the vpn, set OMIT_SENDSIGS
# to 1 and include umountnfs as Required-Stop: in openvpn's
# init.d script (remember to run insserv after that)
#
OMIT_SENDSIGS=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used LXDE's(X11 Desktop environment) 'autostart' file as a start up source for VPN and some other applications. 'autostart' file runs automatically every time the Raspbian starts.

Normally you can find the file at following paths,

**/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart**

or

**~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart**

Just add your application to be run on boot to the file as shown below, using '@' before application name

**@openvpn**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, should that be installed already or do I need to apt-get install something?

Comment: LXDE is the default Desktop environment and it will be installed already. Please check.

Comment: It's not there, I'm guessing because it's RaspBMC rather than a regular linux build so the default desktop environment is the XBMC user interface. Should I look into installing it or is that likely to just destabilise the entire system?

Comment: It will be there in Raspbian by default. I am not sure about RaspBMC. Try this command and let me know. "#sudo update-rc.d openvpn defaults"

Comment: Definitely not there. Can't seem to find a way of installing it as well, I've followed instructions but hasn't worked at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you'd given me a command to try. Not sure how I missed that. I've just tried out the command, and it hasn't made a difference. Interestingly I've been messing about with OSMC over the last couple of days and following the guide I linked to step by step worked perfectly. Is there a difference in the start-up procedures that you (or anyone) are aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't work out what was going on here, but I changed from RaspBMC to Xbian, and it's solved the problem. I think it's because the set up instructions were designed for Raspbian and Xbian is closer to it, though that's just a noob guess.